# How to properly end the thread allocated to a Telegram Telebot?

Tags: python, multithreading, telegram

I am using a Telegram bot to get some statistics on Telegram public channels.

I am facing `MemoryError` and `Error: can't start new thread` on my overall script after having launched several bots.

However I don't need to run them asynchronously, so my question is not about how to handle multiple threads in parallel.

My question is : **how to properly end a Telebot, as well as the WorkerThread(s) automatically dedicated to it ?**

**Minimal sample code:**

```
import telebot
import threading
import gc

print(threading.active_count())  # 5
t = telebot.TeleBot('token')
print(threading.active_count())  # 7
del t
print(threading.active_count())  # 7
gc.collect()
print(threading.active_count())  # 7
```

I would like the number of **active threads to come back to the original 5** (and why not 1, by the way ?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer :

```
print(threading.active_count())  # 5
t = telebot.TeleBot('token')
print(threading.active_count())  # 7
t.stop_bot()
print(threading.active_count())  # 5
```